# GWT + Jsonp + push server stuck after time out

Tags: java, gwt, jsonp, netty

I have been building my GWT app, using JSONP to communicate with a push server (my own code, based on Netty library). The communication function of the GWT app looks like the following, which sends queries stored in in queryList and processes received data from server via function `processDataFromServer`. You may notice that right after a fail or a success of communicating, the function calls itself again for keeping connection with server:

```
ArrayList<String>queryList;
boolean querying = false;

public void queryJsonpServer() {
    if (querying) {
        return;
    }

    querying = true;

    String jsonString = queryList.isEmpty() ? “” : queryList.remove(0);
    String url = postUrl + (!jsonString.isEmpty() ? “?jsonp=" + URL.encodeQueryString(jsonString) : "");

    JsonpRequestBuilder jsonp = new JsonpRequestBuilder();
    jsonp.setTimeout(60 * 1000);

    jsonp.requestObject(url, new AsyncCallback<MyJsonpObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            querying = false;
            queryJsonpServer();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(MyJsonpObject o) {
            processDataFromServer(o);
            querying = false;
            queryJsonpServer();
        }
    });
}
```

The code works fine if the communication are successes (`onSuccess` called).

However, once it fails (`onFailure` called, because of timeout for example), even the function (`queryJsonpServer`) is called again (I am sure a new query is sent, server receives that query and sends back new data), the function is stuck to receive that new data (`onSuccess` has not been called since that fail). After a while `onFailure` called again because of timeout. The problem repeats: query via `onFailure`, receive nothing, `onFailure` called again...

Anyone has idea about that problem? Thanks

Comment: You can try printing out the variable `caught` in `onFailure` to check the case of the error. There may be some problem with the servers return data, for example the server may return a 404 page that gives back a `FileNotFoundException: http://example.com/404`  every time you retry.

Comment: At the moment there is only timeout reason for the failure since I am using local server (both server & GWT app are actually running on my computer) and data sent by server are good ones (my server always prints out everything). I knew I can improve the system to avoid that timeout failure but I need to understand deeper and make my system can run in or recover from any situation